Using hash table via powershell
If a user is a member of the "apps users" and/or "apps test users" group, the Value column will display the relevant group information. if a user is not a member of any group, it will display NULL. how can I do this?
$cyberarkAccounts = Get-ADUser -identity users01 -Properties samaccountname,enabled,memberof

$cyberarkAccountTable = @{}

foreach ($account in $cyberarkAccounts) {

$cyberarkAccountTable[$account.samaccountname] = $account.MemberOf  | %{(Get-ADGroup $_).sAMAccountName} |  Where-Object { $_ -like 'apps Users*' -or $_ -like 'apps test Users*'  }

}

My output:
Name       Value
---        ----
Users01
Users02    apps users
Users03    apps users,apps test Users

My desired output:
Name       Value
---        ----
Users01     NULL
Users02    apps users
Users03    apps users,apps test Users


You're not showing how your output is generated. It's also unclear if you have exactly 2 groups named apps users and apps test users or you have many groups starting with any of those prefixes

I am showing the contents of my cyberarkAccountTable variable.  Yes, there are only these two groups.

Ah my bad sorry didnt realize it was the output from the hashtable

So the only thing that should be changed if you want to display NULL when the user isn't a member of those groups should be an if / else (seems like you're also missing a -join ','):
$cyberarkAccounts = Get-ADUser -Identity users01 -Properties samaccountname, enabled, memberOf
$cyberarkAccountTable = @{}
foreach ($account in $cyberarkAccounts) {
    $result = $account.MemberOf |
        ForEach-Object { (Get-ADGroup $_).sAMAccountName } |
        Where-Object { $_ -like 'apps Users*' -or $_ -like 'apps test Users*' }
    $cyberarkAccountTable[$account.samaccountname] = if ($result) { $result -join ',' } else { 'NULL' }
}

However this approach really is very inefficient if you want to do these checks for many users, a better way to do it would be to get the groups memberships first and map them:
$targetGroups = 'apps Users', 'apps test Users'
$groupMap = @{} # maps key: each item in `$targetGroups` value: hashset with each group member samAccountName
$targetGroups | ForEach-Object {
    $groupDn = (Get-ADGroup $_).DistinguishedName
    $members = (Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(memberOf=$groupDn)").SamAccountName
    $groupMap[$_] = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new(
        [string[]] $members)
}

$cyberarkAccounts = 'user1', 'user2', 'useretc' # these should be samAccountNames!
foreach ($account in $cyberarkAccounts) {
    $membership = foreach ($group in $targetGroups) {
        if ($groupMap[$group].Contains($account)) {
            $group
        }
    }

    [pscustomobject]@{
        User       = $account
        Membership = if ($membership) { $membership -join ',' } else { 'NULL' }
    }
}

